# Visual Studio does not recognize a referenced assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, autofac

Opened an old project from years ago. Build fails because Visual Studio (2019) does not recognize an assembly that is clearly there - specifically, Autofac.

1. You can see it in project references (not marked as missing)
   [image: Project References]
2. You can see it in the Object Browser, listing all the types referenced in the code

[image: In Object Browser]

3. But in code, none of the types show up, gone AWOL.

[image: In code]

What is going on here? Intellisense doesn't even pick up types
(Tried cleaning, rebuilding, re-importing packages)

Comment: missing a using?

Comment: No, its there - using Autofac

Comment: Please show the build error

Comment: This is almost certainly due to a conflict between multiple versions of the same imported project (and it might be a dependency of Autofac rather than Autofac itself). The only way to root out issues like these is to manually audit all of the `ProjectReferece`s to be sure there are no conflicting versions. And since this is a web project, you also need to check the `web.config` to ensure there are no conflicts between it and your project file.

Comment: @Nightowl888 No, there were no conflicts. please see my answer, just by trying random things, i was able to solve it by removing and readding the same dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is what worked. I had to remove the reference to the Autofac dll, and then add it back. Note - I added it back from the same exact location, the same exact version. But after this, Visual Studio 'magically' recognized it.
If you come across a similar problem, and nothing else works, give it a try. I don't know the reason, I can only assume this is some sort of a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: Paying careful attention to the files that change on disk often reveals something in situations like this. You're using source control, such as Git, right? Perhaps reinstalling it fixes incorrect reference in the .csproj, or fixed binding redirects, or something along those lines.

Comment: yes, git. but it was not "reinstalling" (not using package manager), it was really just right-click - remove, and then add it back in the project; it didnt change anything else, not binding redirects, nothing. As i said, I cannot explain, but there it is, a fact, it worked. :)